# How to obtain recent Facebook Post ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to sync FB posts to my own website, which is Drupal site.

I found this embed code that allow me to embed posts to any website.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_CN/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Abner.Ma.1989/posts/411557558943779" data-width="466">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">由
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Abner.Ma.1989">马昕睿</a>贴出
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Abner.Ma.1989/posts/472287552870779">贴子</a>。</div>
</div>
```

You can see if I change the code posts part

`data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Abner.Ma.1989/posts/411557558943779"`

to something else, then the embed content will change too.

So I think this might be one way to sync posts from FB to my own website.

So the question is : How could I obtain recent FB post ID?

Or: Any way to sync FB posts to my own website?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)?

Comment: @SahilMittal No, did that will do what I said?

Comment: Yes of couse, go through it and give it a try1